How to get device enumeration from struct device in Linux kernel module code
I am working with a clock driver for a device which resides on the SPI bus, device is already probed and attached to SPI bus, spidev is struct spidev pointer and spidev->dev points to device and spidev pointer passed in to a function where I print stuff:
dev_dbg(&spidev->dev, "Requested rate: %u", rate); 

and I get

myClockDriver spi1.0: myClock_output_clk_set_rate: Requested rate: 10000000

How is the word "spi1.0" costructed/printed, is it thru one of the elements in struct device? Is it a string or put together as a string from an enumerated value? I get spi1.0 and spi3.0 in my prints. I want to use such an enumeration in my function.
I have tried to print spi->dev->init_name but it seems to be NULL.

dev_dbg() ends up (in the cases when it's not a no-op) in
dev_printk_emit(..., "...%s %s: ...", dev_driver_string(dev), dev_name(dev), ...);

In your case the first string is myClockDriver, which comes from the driver (it's obvious), and the second one is spiX.Y. This as you may notice from the function name comes from the device name. That name for the device comes from the controller name and chip select number (see spi_dev_set_name() implementation:
dev_set_name(&spi->dev, "%s.%u", dev_name(&spi->controller->dev), spi_get_chipselect(spi, 0));

where controller name comes from this line (see implementation of spi_register_controller()):
/*
 * Register the device, then userspace will see it.
 * Registration fails if the bus ID is in use.
 */
dev_set_name(&ctlr->dev, "spi%u", ctlr->bus_num);


0andriy, Thank you very much, its very clear to me now. So if I am looking to do different operation between when the device name is spi1.0 and spi 3.0, could I get the bus_num of the spi controller somehow. Something like spi->controller->bus_num ?

Thank you that worked, I get the two bus IDs 1, 3 as expected. Unfortunately I noticed the bus number order is not in the order that I want them to be, I have upper level routine to set clock for 4 HDMI devices, the order that I want them to be is to use bus 1 for hdmi0, hdmi1 and bus 3 for hdmi2,hdmi3. But what I get is 1,3,1,3.
Is it possible to change this order somehow during probing?

In any case the SPI bus number most likely is dynamically assigned, no one should rely on that. What you may try though is the parent device (AKA physical device) name/path. In some cases it might be parent of parent or even parent of parent of parent. It may be done other way around, i. e. taking SPI controller device pointer (embedded struct device there) and ask if the known physical device is an ancestor of this one. Basically it’s just a loop on the device model tree to the parent and checking the condition against each parent.

Basically I have a custom FPGA SPI module thats dedicated to talk to the clock chip thru the registers mapped (ioremap) mechanism. When the driver gets initialized, the probe is getting called twice , indicating two SPI controllers, spi0, spi1.
Then each clock client such as HDMI devices 0 thru 4 requests a particular clock freq to be set by calling clock ops clk_set_rate on the HDMI device context, which will find its way into the main driver with and set some registers of the FPGA module. These 4 set_rate requests comes into main driver code using one of the two SPI controller contexts

The goal is to assign hdmi0,1 to use spi0 and hdmi2,3 to use spi1.
Right now its picking spi0  for hdmi0,2 and spi1 for hdmi1,3. I think this relationship is inside the dtsi file for hdmi device...
